# Load new page on user control button click

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have user control, which has been loaded to my mainWindow.xaml. There is a button in my user control, now i want to load a new page into mainWindow.xaml 
like

My mainWindow.xaml is like

```
<Window x:Class="HomeWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KioskPrinter"
Title="" Height="1024" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="{StaticResource redStd}" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove" >


<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="_NavigationFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</DockPanel>
```

and mainWindow.xaml.vb

```vb
Public Class HomeWindow

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Style = DirectCast(FindResource(GetType(Window)), Style)

        _NavigationFrame.Navigate(New HomePage())

    End Sub 
End Class
```

Now i have created a user control for my HomePage. In that user control i have a button [Next Page]

Now i want that when i will click on this button a new page will be open to mainwindow.

Please advise.

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you working with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and dirtiest way:

```
_NavigationFrame.Navigate(New HomePage(this))
```

in your HomePage constructor add:

```
Public Sub New(MainWindow mainWindow)
```

and bind that to a property in your HomePage class.

At buttonClick you can call:

```
MainWindow._NavigationFrame.Nagivate(New AnotherPage(this))
```

Be aware that I have no idea how VB works. The examples given will work with C#